# Regex to validate the number which include max one hyphen (-) but that is exclude from the count of characters

Tags: javascript, regex

Regex to validate the number which include max one hyphen (-) but that is exclude from the count of characters

Four digits are allowed with just one hyphen between them.

The example below regular expression also counts the hyphen in for the number of characters:

```
^(?!\D*(\d)(?:\D*\1)+\D*$)(?=.{4}$)[0-9]*(?:-[0-9]*){0,1}[0-9]+$
```

The above one validate the `1112` as its 4 digits, but it will fail `111-2` because there is one hyphen and five digits, which is not allowed.

Examples:

- `1234` allowed as its 4 digits
- `123-4` allowed as we need to skip the hyphen for the count
- `1111` is not allowed as the same digits are used in the string
- `111-1` not allowed as the digits are the same, even separated by hyphen `-`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?!\D*(\d)(?:\D*\1)+\D*$)(?=(?:\D*\d){4}\D*$)[0-9]+(?:-[0-9]+)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BogOrm/2). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!\D*(\d)(?:\D*\1)+\D*$)` - the string cannot contain identical digits regardless of any non-word chars present in string
- `(?=(?:\D*\d){4}\D*$)` - **a positive lookahead that requires four occurrences of any zero or more non-digits followed with a digit, and then any zero or more non-digits till end of string**
- `[0-9]+(?:-[0-9]+)?` - one or more digits, and then an optional occurrence of a `-` and one or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thank you @Wiktor Stribizew, can you help the same with Alpha numerics as well. the above one works for the numeric digits but requirement has both cases like alphabets as well

Comment: @HarinathaReddy In the question, you did not mention *alphanumerics*. In case of alphanumerics, you need to replace `\d` with `[0-9A-Za-z]` and `\D` with `[^0-9A-Za-z]`. Same for `[0-9]`, it should be `[0-9A-Za-z]` to match letters, too.

Comment: It working 

final regex ```^(?![^0-9A-Za-z]*([0-9A-Za-z])(?:[^0-9A-Za-z]*\1)+[^0-9A-Za-z]*$)(?=(?:[^0-9A-Za-z]*[0-9A-Za-z]){4}[^0-9A-Za-z]*$)[0-9A-Za-z]+(?:-[0-9A-Za-z]+)?$ ```

Comment: Hi @Wiktor Stribiżew , small another requirement for the same regex to work in a few cases start with a specific number in the below regex I am trying for the number starts with 97 and the total length is 5. the same logic as its allow maximum 1 hyphen 
tried the below regex ```^97(?![^0-9]*([0-9])(?:[^0-9]*\1)+[^0-9]*$)(?=(?:[^0-9]*[0-9]){3}[^0-9]*$)[0-9]+(?:-[0-9]+)?$``` 
It worked for 97867 and 978-67 but did not work for the 97-867
Could you please correct the above regex?

Comment: @HarinathaReddy `^(?![^0-9]*([0-9])(?:[^0-9]*\1)+[^0-9]*$)(?=(?:[^0-9]*[0-9]){3}[^0-9]*$)97[0-9]*(?:-[0-9]+)?$`

Comment: Hi @Wiktor Stribizew, a small requirement change its max allow one space or - , and that need to be considered as the length of the word trying to use the below one ^(?![^0-9A-Z]*([0-9A-Z])(?:[^0-9A-Z]*\1)+[^0-9A-Z]*$)(?=(?:[^0-9A-Z]*[0-9A-Z]){7}[^0-9A-Z]*$)[0-9A-Z]+(?:(-| )[0-9A-Z]+)?$ 
here its not consider part of the length other than space or - it consider length as 7 but need to find the length as 7 include the space or - but those 2 are optional.

Comment: It [looks fine](https://regex101.com/r/BogOrm/3) to me, could you please add the offending (not working) examples?

Comment: 971-2567 -> it's supposed to be not accepted as the characters are 8 including the hyphen (-) but it accepts.
https://regex101.com/r/3bncPm/1 

971 2567  ->  it's supposed to be not accepted as the characters are 8 including the space ( ) but it accepts.
https://regex101.com/r/sOw95C/1

https://regex101.com/r/zVu2Ln/1 its accepted as 7 characters and working

Comment: @HarinathaReddy So, 7 is the whole string limit then, right? Use `^(?![^0-9A-Z]*([0-9A-Z])(?:[^0-9A-Z]*\1)+[^0-9A-Z]*$)(?=.{7}$)[0-9A-Z]+(?:[- ][0-9A-Z]+)?$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/3bncPm/2))

Comment: Thank you @Wiktor Stribizew, I have updated the below regex as but not working as expected
`^(?![^0-9A-Z]*([0-9A-Z])(?:[^0-9A-Z]*\1)+[^0-9A-Z]*$)(?=.{6,7}$)[0-9A-Z]+(?:[- ][0-9A-Z]+)?$` 

as per the requirement either it allows 6 characters as 123456 or ABC123 and allows either space or hyphen with 7 characters like ABC-123 or ABC 123 but ABC-1234 is not accepted.

Comment: @HarinathaReddy Then use `(?=(?:[^0-9A-Z]*[0-9A-Z]){6,7}[^0-9A-Z]*$)` in your regex. See https://regex101.com/r/3bncPm/3. Or `^(?![^0-9A-Z]*([0-9A-Z])(?:[^0-9A-Z]*\1)+[^0-9A-Z]*$)(?=(?:[^0-9A-Z]*[0-9A-Z]){6}[^0-9A-Z]*$)[0-9A-Z]+(?:[- ][0-9A-Z]+)?$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/3bncPm/4)). Sorry, without exact test cases with the information what must match and what not it is difficult to help.

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor Stribizew, below are the example 
`A12B3C    -> Valid 
ACB1234   -> Valid
123H67J   -> Valid
ABC-123   -> Valid
ANV 123   -> Valid 
ABV-12345 -> Not Valid 
ABC 1234  -> Not Valid 
ABC-12    -> NOT Valid
ABC 12    -> Not Valid
ABV--35 -> Not Valid
AV- 345 -> Not Valid  
AV- 124 -> Not Valid 
AV- 124 -> Not Valid 
AV-12 5 -> Not Valid 
AV-12 5 -> Not Valid 
`

Comment: @HarinathaReddy You already asked a question and got a working answer for that.

Comment: one case is failing is the below example https://regex101.com/r/yB1lTp/1 if included hyphen or space max length is 7

I am using the below regex is working as expected other than the one case like it's not to allow unique characters 
^[A-Z0-9]{6,7}$|(?=^.{7}$)^[A-Z0-9]+[- ]?[A-Z0-9]+$
like 111111 it's not allowed but allowing this

Comment: 1111-11 not Valid 
AAAAAA Not Valid
AAAAAAB   Valid
11111 1    Not Valid

Comment: Look [here](https://regex101.com/r/yB1lTp/2), all works as expected, right?

Comment: No @Wiktor Stribizew, one case failing ABC 5123  here the length of the string is 8 but if we included either the space or Hyphen the length should be 7.

Comment: @HarinathaReddy So, if you want to count in only letters or digits when checking the string length, then add `-` and space to the negated character classes in the lookahead: `^(?![^0-9A-Z]*([0-9A-Z])(?:[^0-9A-Z]*\1)+[^0-9A-Z]*$)(?=(?:[^0-9A-Z -]*[0-9A-Z]){6,7}[^0-9A-Z -]*$)[0-9A-Z]+(?:[- ][0-9A-Z]+)?$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/yB1lTp/3))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247844/discussion-between-harinatha-reddy-and-wiktor-stribizew).